# Qt Creator4.4.1 hide blank line(Screenshot attached)

Tags: qt-creator

I dont want to hide the blank line.but i dont have any ideas.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOlgt.png)

Answer (score 1):

same problem with Qt Creator 4.6.2
looks like Creator was broken after office blackout
clean folder QtProject from AppData didn't help
upgrade to Qt Creator 4.8.1 also didn't help

discussion there
https://forum.qt.io/topic/98869/qt-creator-4-6-2-hide-blank-lines-in-code-editor

and reported bug there
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-21191

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Display` and *check* `Display folding markers`. 
Or go to the line and press `Ctrl + Shift + .` (`Ctrl + >`) to unfold the lines.

Comment: sorry,i never unchecked it. i tried again, it didnt work.